# Does non-content posts have a negative impact on SEO?

Tags: custom-post-types, seo

By non-content posts I mean records in wp_posts table that have custom post_types, such as custom layouts, headers, templates, etc.

I see all of these "posts" actually have their own permalink, which means everyone can access them from the frontend if they know the permalink.

Will they be crawled by spiders? Does having these "pseudo" pages in your website have a negative impact on SEO? If yes, is there any sophisticated solution for this?

Comment: When creating a custom post type that you know is never going to be an actual page you can set it to private. That way you can create as many posts as you want without the fear of creating crawlable links that you never intend to create a deisgn for or be an actual page

Comment: Spiders generally only crawl links that they can access from the frontend. If these layouts aren't linked anywhere from your frontend or sitemap, then it shouldn't be an issue. Some plugins like Yoast SEO allow you to noindex these post types if you're not sure. I doubt these layouts have a noticeable negative impact on SEO, though even if crawled. [Webmasters StackExchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) may know more as SEO is one of their specialities.

Comment: Please note that the guid column is _not_ a publicly accessible link. It is just a unique identifier. WordPress uses a URL for legacy reasons.